# Does return use move or copy semantics by default?

Tags: c++, c++17

Moving from C# to C++, trying to understand what happens under the hood.

Given:

```
int ReturnSomething(){
    int i = 1;
    return i;
}
```

Is move prioritized over copy in C++17? If so, would the same rules apply for user-defined types, where move constructors are explicitly defined?

Comment: pretty sure that if you're returning a local it will be moved, if not elided.  It's pretty easy to check, though, as you can just put a print statement in your move and copy constructors and see which is called.

Comment: For primitive types like `int`, there is no difference between copy and move.

Comment: Moving is actually about resource ownership transfer, it doesn't "move" memory

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Yeah, thus why it's more performant as far as I could understand. But is it prioritized over copy in modern C++? If what I've read so far is correct, it wasn't in older C++ versions, but nowhere that I could find is it stated how it works in C++17

Comment: When returning, RVO/NRVO will actually kick in whenever possible - as it actually avoids completely the temporary. But conceptually, returning is equivalent to initializing an instance with the value you pass to `return`. If it's an rvalue, move will be used if available, otherwise copy will be used ((N)RVO notwithstanding).

Comment: Here's an example of RVO and NRVO kicking in: https://ideone.com/jeQmp2 Note no copies or moves whatsoever.

Comment: @ReousaAsteron: Older versions didn't _have_ move operations.

Comment: @MooingDuck wasn't it introduced in C++0x? O.o

Comment: @user4581301 Except in C++17, NRVO is the only type of RVO. In other places where RVO used to be permitted, there simply are fewer formal temporary objects involved in the first place, so there's nothing to "optimize".

Comment: Took me a few reads, and a quick dive into the Standard,  to parse that, @aschepler . Correct me if I'm wrong, but you are saying there is no RVO because the handling of temporaries changed, effectively making what was called RVO  meaningless? So RVO isn't mandatory in C++17 so much as it was rendered obsolete?

Comment: @user4581301 I kind of got to the same conclusion, I am legit confused right now. I'm assuming it's just safer to strictly use `std::move` when I want to `return move` rather than `return copy`, but I'm not entirely sure if that stops some compiler optimizations from happening.

Comment: @ReousaAsteron  I suggest working the other way around. Operate off the assumption that you will get move or elision, then check the code. If you don't get elision, and you don't get move, and profiling tells you you need the move, then move. But odds are if you didn't get at least a move out of the compiler, the compiler probably knows something you don't. As always profile.

Comment: @user4581301 The C++17 change is sometimes called "mandatory copy elision" because one of its effects is to change the behavior of lots of code from "the compiler might or might not invoke a copy/move constructor and destructor here" to "the compiler will not invoke ...". But it does a bit more than that: some code which was invalid because of using a deleted or inaccessible copy/move constructor can now be valid, because the new rules don't describe a temporary object and a copy/move constructor at all.

Comment: @user4581301 ... So you could say the effect of the prvalue changes from C++14 C++17 are to require copy elision *and* skip certain semantic checks for the elided copy/move constructor.  But the actual language in the Standard is arranged so that the code in those cases just doesn't imply any temporary object or copy/move constructor in the first place.

Comment: @ReousaAsteron Usually a plain `return` without `std::move` will do the "right thing", and adding `std::move` can force a move constructor + destructor to be used where there were none, or where it was the compiler's choice whether to invoke them or not.  Unless you have a strangely defined class, it will never do a full copy if you have a simple `return var;` where `var` is local to the function, or if you `return some_func();` where `some_func` returns by value.

Comment: @ReousaAsteron ... The main cases where it might make sense to `return std::move(something);` would be if `something` is a name not local to the function, a member access expression (`.` or `->`), a built-in dereference expression (`*ptr` or `arr[i]`), or a function that returns an lvalue reference type, including overloaded operators.  All of these leave the possibility that something else could still use the moved-from object, so this needs to be an intentional choice.

Comment: @aschepler This really clears up a lot, thanks! Conclusion is that in essence, I should trust the compiler (which makes sense, really) to do the right thing, until I need not to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does return use move or copy semantics by default?

Depends.

> Is move prioritized over copy in C++17?

The exact rules are a bit complicated, but in general, if move is possible then it is preferred over copy.

In some cases, there isn't even a move. For example:

```
T ReturnSomething(){
    return 1;
}
T t = ReturnSomething();
```

There is no copying involved. An object is allocated for the `t` variable, and `ReturnSomething` initialises that object directly. There is no temporary object involved.

Of course, there is no observable difference when the type is trivially movable / copyable like `int` is. Even if there was a copy, it could be optimised away. And there is no difference between copying and moving an integer.

Comment: Would it be possible to include a reference to the rules you mentioned? I really want to get my head wrapped around this concept before I move to the next.

Comment: @ReousaAsteron Checkout sections [basic.lval], [stmt.return], [dcl.init], [class.temporary] [class.copy.elision] of the standard for a start.

Comment: The particular rule about move vs. copy for a return statement is [\[class.copy.elision\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.elision#3). (But yes, some of those other sections will be helpful in understanding exactly what it says.)